# Why am i getting RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback from asyncio.run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

I have written a small api wrapper and i wanted to try to put it in a discord bot using discord.py. I tried using requests, grequests and aiohttp for the requests, but that didn't work. The code that is throwing the error is the following:

```py
async def _get(url):
    return await requests.get(url)

def getUser(name):
    url = 'some url'
    resp = asyncio.run(_get(url))
```

and the error is:

```
/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py:81: RuntimeWarning: coroutine '_get' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

this seems to be an issue just when using discord py, as the actual code works fine in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests.get()` is synchronous, so awaiting it is useless, however `_get` is. Since `requests` is synchronous, you'll have to use [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/):

```py
# Set json to True if the response uses json format
async def _get(link, headers=None, json=False):
    async with ClientSession() as s:
        async with s.get(link, headers=headers) as resp:
            return await resp.json() if json else await resp.text()

async def getUser(name):
    url = 'some url'
    resp = await _get(url)
```

If you don't want `getUser` to be asynchronous, you can use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#scheduling-from-other-threads):

```py
from asyncio import run_coroutine_threadsafe

def getUser(name):
    url = 'some url'
    resp = run_coroutine_threadsafe(_get(url), bot.loop) #or client.loop
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to point out that, for the `run_coroutine_threadsafe` example to work, the event loop has to actually be _running_, presumably in a separate thread.